# Passing params[:id] to create method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a create method that collects the ID of the profile the user is currently viewing, along with some other information that is irrelevant to this question. However, because the create method POSTs rather than GETs (as I understand it), the value of `params[:id]` doesn't exist so it's always null. My code is as follows:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @Post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @Post = Post.new(post_params)   
        @Post.user_id = current_user.id
        @Post.target_id = params[:id] #this

        if @Post.save
            redirect_to :back, notice: "You added a post!"
        end
    end

    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:body)
        end
end
```

Is there a way to get the value of `params[:id]` from elsewhere, perhaps from my Users controller in the show method where it actually exists?

Keep in mind that I was successfully able to create a hidden field in the Posts form, but I didn't like the fact that users were able to edit the value using Developer Tools, allowing them to change what profile the post would go to.

Comment: You can have nested resources like user/1/posts

Comment: I guess you're using `devise`. So, only authenticate_user can create a `post`. Use `current_user.id` without using nested routes.

Comment: Well, if the user were to change the target id, they'd post to another target, so joke on them. 2. Like @Triveni says, we'd expect the route to be nested in there, which is basically a fancier way of using a hidden parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a direct relation between the Target and the Post model, you should express this in the controller and model structure: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

This expresses your intention and it provides all the rails automations like routing, url helpers, form helpers, a.s.o.

In your concrete example, my guess is the Target would have many Posts:

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target
end
```

Which would lead to the following route structure:

```
resources :targets do
  resources :posts
end
```

To create a new post for the current target you would post to:

```
targets/:target_id/posts
```

And the target id would be accessed via params[:target_id]

Comment: Note path in my edit is incorrect. It should be targets/:target_id/posts system won't let me edit one letter!